# Is there a way to limit query results by values in an IN list?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following database table:

```
myTable:
----------------------------------------
| customID | value |     timestamp     |
----------------------------------------
|   e01    | key01 |  11-11-2019 04:00 |
|   e02    | key02 |  11-11-2019 04:01 |
|   e02    | key03 |  11-11-2019 04:02 |
|   e02    | key04 |  11-11-2019 04:03 |
|   e03    | key05 |  11-11-2019 04:04 |
|   e03    | key06 |  11-11-2019 04:05 |
|   e03    | key07 |  11-11-2019 04:06 |
|   e03    | key08 |  11-11-2019 04:07 |
----------------------------------------
```

I would like to query for a list of `customIDs`, where the list is limited to a certain number for each `customID`.

For example, I'd like to do a query similar to this:

```
SELECT
  customID,
  value,
  timestamp
FROM
  myTable
WHERE
  customID
IN
  (e02, e03)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT (2, 3);
```

which would give me the following result:

```
  customID | value |      timestamp 
-----------+-------+--------------------
|   e02    | key03 |  11-11-2019 04:02 |
|   e02    | key04 |  11-11-2019 04:03 |
|   e03    | key06 |  11-11-2019 04:05 |
|   e03    | key07 |  11-11-2019 04:06 |
|   e03    | key08 |  11-11-2019 04:07 |
```

How is a reasonably efficient way of doing this?  I would rather not do a UNION or JOIN if possible.

Comment: Limit doesn't work like that.  This is just  a max in group question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by customID order by timestamp desc) rn
    from mytable
    where customID in ('e02', 'e03')
) t
WHERE 
    (customID = 'e02' and rn <= 2)
    or (customID = 'e03' and rn <= 3)
```

Comment: That looks like it will work. I'll give it a try, and if so, I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient method is probably `union all`:

```
(SELECT customID, value, timestamp
 FROM myTable
 WHERE customID = 'e02'
 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
 LIMIT 2
) UNION ALL
(SELECT customID, value, timestamp
 FROM myTable
 WHERE customID = 'e03'
 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
 LIMIT 3
);
```

With an index on `(customID, timestamp DESC)` it is hard to imagine any other formulation being faster.